# Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CU7 Synchronization taking hours to complete

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CU7.  I have removed the Foundation Upgrade and Update for Foundation Update models from the modelstore and it is taking hours - no really, hours - to complete a database synchronization.  The estimated remaining time is 27 hours as I am typing this.  This seems accurate, because it has been running for 16 hours so far.

Any idea why AX is acting more like it is running on a 386 than the machine it is actually on?

Host specs:
32GB RAM
1TB Disk
16 cores (4x4)

Normally, this process takes 10-20 minutes, tops.

Comment: Have you tried restarting AOS and repeat synchronization?

Comment: I saw this happen on the first sync after turning off the keep update objects configuration key. Watching it in SQL activity monitor, the kernel was dropping the not null constraint individually for each field before deleting the field. Dropping the constraint was taking 10s of seconds for each field, I didn't figure out why.

Comment: How's your environemnt setup? Single server on SQL on another box?